# Select column names and querying "LIKE" on Couchbase

Tags: sql, couchbase, sql++

I want to get all column names from a bucket.

I found a query:

```
SELECT ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_AGG(v)) AS column
FROM mybucket b UNNEST object_names(b) AS v
```

It's getting column names array but I need `LIKE` SQL command. It's like this:

```
SELECT column
FROM mybucket
WHERE column LIKE '%test%'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one, depending on what you want the resultant structure to be. And disclaimer, there might be a more succinct way to do this (but I haven't found it yet--maybe there's another way that doesn't involve `OBJECT_NAMES`?).

But anyway, the key to this for me was the [`ARRAY` collection operator](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#array).

For instance, this:

```
SELECT ARRAY a FOR a IN ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_AGG(allFieldNames))
       WHEN a LIKE '%test%' END AS filteredFieldNames
FROM mybucket b UNNEST object_names(b) AS allFieldNames
```

Will return results like

```
[
  {
    "filteredFieldNames": [
      "testField1",
      "anotherTestField"
    ]
  }
]
```

If you want a different format, you can work with the ARRAY operator expression. For instance:

```
SELECT ARRAY { "fieldName" : a } FOR a IN 
       ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_AGG(allFieldNames))
       WHEN a LIKE '%test%' END AS filteredFieldNames
FROM mybucket b UNNEST object_names(b) AS allFieldNames
```

Which would return:

```
[
  {
    "filteredFieldNames": [
      {
        "fieldName": "testField1"
      },
      {
        "fieldName": "anotherTestField"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

OBJECT_NAMES() only gives top level field names (not includes nested fields)
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/objectfun.html

```
SELECT DISTINCT v AS column
FROM mybucket b UNNEST OBJECT_NAMES(b) AS v
WHERE v LIKE "%test%";
```